# как удалить строки в которых присутствуют стоп слова

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, pandas, re

Читаю большой текстовый файл по кускам с помощью Pandas.

Список:

```
1@vmail.ss:1@23
12@vmail.ss:1@23
123@vmail.ss:123@
12345@vmail.ss:131
123456@vmail.ss:1@31
1234567@vmail.ss:131
12345678@vmail.ss:131
```

Пример - блек лист слова списком:

```
1@
123456@
12345678@
```

На выходе хочу получить:

```
12@vmail.ss:1@23
123@vmail.ss:123@
12345@vmail.ss:131
1234567@vmail.ss:131
```

Важна быстрая работа, поэтому построчное чтение файла не подходит. Требуется регулярка для работы сразу с большим списком) Надо рассматривать только эту часть `12@vmail.ss`
точнее, до первого `@`.

Comment: Вы хотите проверять только с начала строки или на вхождение в любом месте строки? И чем обусловлен выбор Pandas? Почему не “grep” или “awk”? Они точно будут быстрее чем Pandas

Comment: И почему регулярка? В чёрном списке подстроки или регулярные выражения?

Comment: Я новичек , и ничего не слышал про  “grep” или “awk”) 
В чёрном списке подстроки

Comment: Если `1@` в черном списке,то почему тогда в результате присутствует `12@vmail.ss:1@23`? В этой строке присутствует подстрока `1@`!

Comment: потому что надо рассматривать только эту часть `12@vmail.ss`

Comment: точнее , до первого @ включительно

Comment: вся эта информация должна стоять в вопросе и ее надо указывать сразу)

Comment: прошу прощения, писал поздно ночью , видимо голова уже не хотела соображать ))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну я бы использовал [pandas.Series.startswith](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html). Там, как ни странно, можно использовать `tuple` из набора строк в качестве аргумента:

```
import pandas as pd

email_list = """1@vmail.ss:1@23
12@vmail.ss:1@23
123@vmail.ss:123@
12345@vmail.ss:131
123456@vmail.ss:1@31
1234567@vmail.ss:131
12345678@vmail.ss:131""".split()

black_list = ('1@', '123456@', '12345678@')

df = pd.DataFrame({'email': email_list})

df[~df.email.str.startswith(black_list)]
```

Результат:

```
    email
1   12@vmail.ss:1@23
2   123@vmail.ss:123@
3   12345@vmail.ss:131
5   1234567@vmail.ss:131
```